# How to export dataframe from google collaboration as .h5?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to export dataframe in `.h5` format from Google Colab, the package I'm using to do downstream analysis reads in that format so would like it to export in that specific file format.

I know to export it into csv file format you do:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('drive')
adata.to_csv('adata.csv')
!cp df.csv "drive/My Drive/"
```

but I am not sure what is the right command is to execute export into .h5 format. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `to_hdf` method:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('drive')
adata.to_hdf('adata.h5', key='adata')
!cp adata.h5 "drive/My Drive/"
```